# How do I remove duplicates based on three columns, but I keep the row with the highest number in the specific column using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 Unique Id|Class Id|Version Id
       501        1          1
       602        3          1
       602        3          1
       405        2          1
       305        2          3
       305        2          2
       305        1          1
       305        2          1
       509        1          1
       501        2          1
       501        3          1
       501        3          2
       602        2          1
       602        1          1
       405        1          1
```

If I were to run the script the remaining entries should be:

```
 Unique Id|Class Id|Version Id
       501        1          1
       602        3          1
       405        2          1
       305        2          3
       305        1          1
       509        1          1
       501        2          1
       501        3          2
       602        2          1
       602        1          1
       405        1          1
```

Note that Unique id:501 Class id:3 and Version id:2 was selected instead because it has the highest Version id. Note Unique id:602 Class id:3 and VersionId:1 is deleted because it is exactly the same from beginning to end.

Basically I want the script to delete all duplicates based on three columns and leave the row with the highest version id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rleid` on the `UniqueID` column and do `slice_max` after grouping by the `rleid` on 'Unique Id' and `Class Id`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
data %>%      
  group_by(grp = rleid(`Unique Id`), `Class Id`) %>% 
  slice_max(`Version Id`) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp) %>%
  distinct
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
#   `Unique Id` `Class Id` `Version Id`
#         <int>      <int>        <int>
# 1         501          1            1
# 2         602          3            1
# 3         405          2            1
# 4         305          1            1
# 5         305          2            3
# 6         509          1            1
# 7         501          2            1
# 8         501          3            2
# 9         602          1            1
#10         602          2            1
#11         405          1            1
```

---

Or if we don't have to consider the `Unique Id` with adjacent blocks as one

```
data %>%
    group_by(`Unique Id`, `Class Id`) %>%
    slice_max(`Version Id`) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    distinct
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
ind <- with(rle(data$`Unique Id`), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
data1 <- data[order(ind, -data$`Version Id`),]
data1[!duplicated(cbind(ind, data1$`Class Id`)),]
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(`Unique Id` = c(501L, 602L, 602L, 405L, 305L, 
305L, 305L, 305L, 509L, 501L, 501L, 501L, 602L, 602L, 405L), 
    `Class Id` = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), `Version Id` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: Does this take into account the other two columns like class and version?

Comment: @user35131 I think the solution now matches your expected

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for!! Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If the order doesn't matter then we can reorder the data so that higher version IDs are on top, and then remove duplicated entries.

```
df <- df[order(df[,1], df[,2], -df[,3]),]
df <- df[!duplicated(df[,-3]),]

df
       Unique Id Class Id Version Id
7        305        1          1
5        305        2          3
15       405        1          1
4        405        2          1
1        501        1          1
10       501        2          1
12       501        3          2
9        509        1          1
14       602        1          1
13       602        2          1
2        602        3          1
```

Comment: If the order is important, it's still there in the `rownames(df)` too.